# movq (%rsi), %rcx Could someone tell me what does this mean?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel

This is a line in ../sysdeps/x86_64/memcpy.S, I got VM crash after this line so I need to know what's happened. Basically I know it's something like copy rsi to rcx. But does this mean that rsi and rcx themselves should be both valid addresses? 
Because when I type "info registers", I got:

```
rcx            0xfa7e828    262662184
rsi            0x9  9
```

And when I use "x/s" to see what's in the address, I got:

```
(gdb) x/s 0x7fb47787e820
0x7fb47787e820:  ""
(gdb) x/s 0xfa7e828
0xfa7e828:   <Address 0xfa7e828 out of bounds>
(gdb) p $rsi
$2 = 9
(gdb) x/s 0x9
0x9:     <Address 0x9 out of bounds>
```

Actually "0x09" is the value, not the address of the value, that I would like to copy into some place. So is it because that this line of code is treating "0x09" as some address, and hence got the below fault?

```
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
memcpy () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/memcpy.S:102
102     movq    (%rsi), %rcx
```

If it helps, the backtrace and code around that line are:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  memcpy () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/memcpy.S:102
#1  0x00007fb484688f68 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fb4830399d1 in start_thread (arg=0x7fb464af8700) at pthread_create.c:301
#3  0x00007fb482d86b7d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:115
(gdb) l
97  
98  L(1c):                  /* 8-byte once */
99      testb   $8, %dl
100     jz  L(1d)
101 
102     movq    (%rsi), %rcx
103     movq    %rcx, (%rdi)
104 
105     addq    $8, %rsi
106     addq    $8, %rdi
(gdb) 
107 
108     .p2align 4,, 4
109 
110 L(1d):                  /* 16-byte loop */
111     andl    $0xf0, %edx
112     jz  L(exit)
113 
114     .p2align 4
115 
116 L(1loop):
```

Thanks very much for all your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDB is giving you key information. The source address 0x9 is out of bounds and you are telling that 0x9 is actually the value to copy. Therefore, you are not passing to memcpy a valid source address but the value instead.

Maybe you are passing a variable `x` instead of its address `&x`:

```
...
x = 9;
memcpy(destination_address, x, N); //<-- should be &x
```

Same consideration must be taken into account for `destination_address`. If it's a variable, dereference with the `&` operator. If it's a pointer, pass it as is.

Comment: OK. So my previous inquiry should be: the value in "rsi" and "rcx", are they the actual value or just the address that holds the value? And based on your answer, they should be the address... I'm not using memcpy here, just a libvmi write function which will eventually call the system write() function. So I guess I'll try to figure out that libvmi write() function then.

Comment: The (%rsi) means to use %rsi as an address to a memory location. The movq means move quad word (8 byte value).